# Why twbs:bootstrap package is not recoginized by Meteor?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, meteor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package for login. But the dropdown menu doesn't work.

when I check the console, I get the following error

```
ian_accounts-ui-bootstrap-3.js?hash=e27c970…:5495 You have to add a Bootstrap package, i.e. meteor add twbs:bootstrap
```

I already have `twbs:bootstrap` installed.

- Tried re-installing `ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3` package alone - Didn't work
- Tried re-installing `twbs:bootstrap` package - didn't work
- Tried re-installing both packages at once using the following commands respectively:

  ```
  1) meteor remove twbs:bootstrap ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3

  2) meteor add twbs:bootstrap ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
  ```

the problem is yet to be resolved.

Based on the console, I should install a package in which I already installed.

How do I get the project to recognize `twbs:bootstrap` package?

Comment: To check, is accounts ui removed and a package like accounts password installed?

Comment: @NicholasByDesign, yes, accounts-ui is removed, and accounts-password is installed